# Creating 3x3 "square legend" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

Is it possible to create this type of *"square legend"* in QGIS?

It is the first time that I see this type of legend and I really liked it.

[image: square lengend]

Source: https://twitter.com/Caroline_OF_B/status/1249699201392484354

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is not an out of the box way of getting a legend like this in QGIS.

[Here](https://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/) a tutorial (Bivariate Choropleth Map, using QGIS) that suggest using graphic software to create the legend independently. As QGIS now include blending using another software is not strictly necessary and you should be able to use the same methodology directly in your layout. But as it's still manually creating the legend using other software could be quicker or simpler (and maybe give better result).

For comparaison [this tutorial](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2012/08/24/making-value-by-alpha-maps-with-arcmap/) show how it could be done in ArcMap (still manually creating the square legend by converting to graphic and editing the ArcMap created legend)

Answer (score 4):

The plugin  [Bivariate Legend](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BivariateLegend/) suggested by @Kazuhito in a comment did what I was looking for.