# Making one legend from two multiplied layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I'm very new to QGIS and was wondering how I can make a legend for two seperate layers that are multiplied. The two layers selected in the picture underneath are the ones I multiplied and I would like to use the multiplied colors to make one legend of 9 combinations (3x3).

[image: The two selected layers are the ones that are multiplied]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create 3x3 "square legend" using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359485/create-3x3-square-legend-using-qgis)

The Bivarite Legend plugin should be enough :

https://github.com/webgeodatavore/bivariate_legend/